# Where to put customized config file for KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: airflow

In [Airflow KubernetesPodOperator document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#howto-operator-kubernetespodoperator) it says "Users can specify a kubeconfig file using the config_file parameter, otherwise the operator will default to ~/.kube/config." My question is if I have a local customized kubernete config file where to put it? Can I simply specify config_file="~/myconfig.yml" and Airflow cluster will know where to find it?

Comment: Inside Kubernetes, usually, No, it won't, how are you deploying? using [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/airflow-helm/airflow)?

Comment: Did you find the solution @Yinfang?